# Why am I getting TimeoutException in Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Just started learning Selenium with Python. And no matter how much I change the WebDriverWait, it's still giving me the TimeoutException.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


url = 'https://bbrauncareers-bbraun.icims.com/jobs/search?ss=1&searchRelation=keyword_all'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.description')))


print(title)
```

The page loads fully on driver.get(url), but it doesn't seem to want to find the title. I tried changing the css selector to anything else on the page, and it's still the same. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you!

Comment: `div.description` this is returning 20 elements. Can you point at the web element you want to locate and read?

Comment: @Shawn Ultimately, I'd like to be able to loop through all descriptions on the page. But at the moment, I'd just like to figure out how to get one at least. So I know something is working.

Comment: Use different expected condition method, I suggest to use the "presenceOfElementLocated()" instead of the Visibilityofelementoflocated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [IFRAME](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/) which is wrapping the desired element inside. You need to switch into the `IFRAME` first, then you need to perform the action you want on the desired element.

**Refer the below code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://bbrauncareers-bbraun.icims.com/jobs/search?ss=1&searchRelation=keyword_all")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

# below line will switch into the IFRAME
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "icims_content_iframe")))

title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[contains(@class,'description')])[1]")))
print(title.text)

# Below line will come out of IFRME
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**Console output:**

```
About B. Braun    B. Braun Medical Inc., a leader in infusion therapy and pain management, develops, manufactures, and markets innovative medical products and services to the healthcare industry. Other key product areas include nutrition, pharmacy admixture and compounding, ostomy and wound care, and dialysis. The company is committed to eliminating preventable treatment errors and enhancing patient, clinician and environmental safety. B. Braun Medical is headquartered in Bethlehem, Pa., and is part of the B. Braun Group of Companies in the U.S., which includes B. Braun Interventional Systems, Aesculap® and CAPS®.   Globally, the B. Braun Group of Companies employs more than 61,000 employees in 64 countries. Guided by its Sharing Expertise® philosophy, B. Braun continuously exchanges knowledge with customers, partners and clinicians to address the critical issues of improving care and lowering costs. To learn more about B. Braun Medical, visit www.BBraunUSA.com.  

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Shawn. I had no idea I had to look out for that, too.